# Returning Generic.Type for later use with class methods

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to return a type of generic that conforms to protocol for later use with class functions using Swift 1.2? Take a look:

```
protocol SomeProtocol
{
    static func start(kind: Kind)
}

class A: SomeProtocol
{
    class func start(kind: Kind)
    {
        print("A started")
    }
}

class B: SomeProtocol
{
    class func start(kind: Kind)
    {
        print("B started")
    }
}


enum Kind {
    case Akind
    case Bkind

    private func classKind<T: SomeProtocol>() -> T.Type
    {
        switch self {
            case .Akind: return A.self
            case .Bkind: return B.self
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        self.classKind().start(self)
    }
}
```

I tried various methods but every of them ended with some errors. Currently I got 'A' is not a subtype of 'T' in classKind method (same for 'B') and cannot invoke 'start' with an argument list of type '(Kind)' in doSomething. 
I'm sure I'm pretty close but can't solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Swift 2, to achieve what you want you only need to change:

```
private func classKind<T: SomeProtocol>() -> T.Type { ... }
```

to

```
private func classKind() -> SomeProtocol.Type { ... }
```

---

Now back to the not-working code to see where the errors were coming from. You don't need to make the changes I'm now detailing, this is just to explain the errors.

First examine your `doSomething` method:

```
func doSomething() {
    self.classKind().start(self) 
    // Error: Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred.
    // 
    // (I'm using Xcode 7 b6, which may explain the differing error messages)
}
```

For the type returned by `classKind` to be inferred, you'd have to do:

```
let type: A.Type = self.classKind() // Or you could use `B.Type`.
type.start(self)
```

Which obviously defeats the point of your goal, since you have to specify the type you want.

---

Secondly, the errors in `classKind`:

```
private func classKind<T: SomeProtocol>() -> T.Type
{
    switch self {
    case .Akind: return A.self 
    // Cannot convert return expression of type 'A.Type' to return type 'T.Type'. 

    case .Bkind: return B.self
    // Cannot convert return expression of type 'B.Type' to return type 'T.Type'.
    }
}
```

To see why this doesn't work consider the following example, in which I have another type that conforms to `SomeProtocol`:

```
struct C: SomeProtocol { ... }
```

Then in `doSomething`:

```
func doSomething() {
    let type: C.Type = self.classKind()
    type.start(self)
}
```

The errors you're getting can now be read as: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'A.Type'/'B.Type' to return type 'C.Type'`.

Comment: So, there's no way to archieve what I want? My main goal is to use `type.start(…)` in `doSomething` method without explicit writing explicit type.

Comment: In the first bit on my answer I said what you need to do to make it work :) I edited my answer to hopefully make that a bit clearer.

Comment: After, your change `classKind() -> SomeProtocol.Type` in `doSomething()` I get: Accessing members of protocol type value 'SomeProtocol.Type' is unimplemented

Comment: Ahh okay, that's because you're using Swift 1.2, with Swift 2 that works fine. I'm not sure this is something you'll be able to have working in Swift 1.2 unfortunately...

Comment: Ohh… Apple should be more specific "… is unimplemented by us. Stay tuned." would be nice ;)